# Extracting a time series from a sound object

Tags: matrix, sound, time-series

After importing a sound file, how can I generate a time series (preferably as an $n\times 1$ matrix) which gives the intensity at equal time intervals?

Answer (score 6):

Let the imported sound be

```
sound = ExampleData[{"Sound", "JetSound"}]
```

One can extract the [`SampledSoundList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SampledSoundList.html?q=SampledSoundList) with

```
sound[[1]]
```

This example has 2 channels and a sampling rate of 44100 Hz, as can be seen not only in the sound object box, but also from

```
Length@sound[[1, 1]]
```

> `2`

```
sound[[1, 2]]
```

> `44100`

To get the list of the amplitudes of the first channel one can use

```
channel1Amp = sound[[1, 1, 1]];
```

and generate a plot of these amplitudes using

```
ListPlot[channel1Amp, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: Channel1Amplitudes]

The amplitudes of the second channel are

```
channel2Amp = sound[[1, 1, 2]];
```

---

### Downsampling

Downsampling the first channel by a factor of 5

```
channel1AmpDS = Downsample[channel1Amp, 5];

ListPlot[channel1AmpDS, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: downsampledChannel1]

There is also [`Upsample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Upsample.html) and the more general [`ArrayResample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html) that can be used to change the sampling rate.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change the sampling rate?

Comment: @SankhadipChakraborty The question in your comment isn't very specific. Please check the edit of my answer. Hope you didn't mean something like `newSound = sound;
newSound[[1, -1]] = 10000;
newSound`.